# How to strip newline from shell command's standard output run via ansible

Tags: python, jinja2, ansible

So I have a scenario where I am executing a shell command on a machine using ansible to get some information on standard output .  I am using `register` to log its result in a variable `my_info` and print `my_info` using `debug` , I am seeing its result with `\n` appended to it (Ansible has appended \n .Same command on linux do not appends \n" ).When I use the `my_info` in templates for a config it prints a new line in config hence messing up my config .

Here is how the code and output goes .

Ansible code :

```
- name: calculate range address start
  raw:  grep 'CONFIG_PARAMS' /path/to/the/file | head -n 1
  register: my_info
```

Output :

```
ok: [My_HOST] => {
    "msg": "CONFIG_PARAMS\n"
}
```

How can we strip the space from this output or possibly make a change in template so that new line don't gets printed .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the documentation of [raw_module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/raw_module.html), it asks to use it only in specific cases:

> Executes a low-down and dirty SSH command, not going through the module subsystem. This is useful and should only be done in two cases. The first case is installing `python-simplejson` on older (Python 2.4 and before) hosts that need it as a dependency to run modules, since nearly all core modules require it. Another is speaking to any devices such as routers that do not have any Python installed. In any other case, using the `shell` or `command` module is much more appropriate. Arguments given to raw are run directly through the configured remote shell.

So, I tested simple echo calls with `raw` and `shell` modules:

```
- name: System setup
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - name: simple print hello
      raw:  echo 'hello'
      register: my_info

    - debug:
        msg: '{{ my_info.stdout }}'
```

and it outputs with a new line:

```
TASK: [debug ]    **************************************************************** 
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "hello\n"
}
```

and by using the `shell` module:

```
- name: System setup
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - name: simple print hello
      action:  shell echo 'hello'
      register: my_info

    - debug:
        msg: '{{ my_info.stdout }}'
```

and this results in:

```
TASK: [debug ]    **************************************************************** 
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "hello"
}
```

And, you can see the difference in the output.

Comment: This is a much better approach. I've yet to see a good reason to ever use the `raw` other than against system that don't have Python installed and that use case should then be to use `raw` to set up Python.

Comment: @AKS  you are right . `raw` command should not be used until its needed as per the defined usecase in the docs  . I have change it to `shell` . Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 16):

You can use the built-in filters of [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/) to achieve this. Specifically, use `trim`, e.g.:

```
- debug: msg='{{ my_info.stdout | trim}}'
```

Answer (score 3):

You could remove the newline from stdout, using

```
grep 'CONFIG_PARAMS' /path/to/the/file | head -n 1 | tr -d '\n'
```

If you run this on a command-line you'll see something like

```
me@machine:~ > echo cat | tr -d '\n'
catme@machine:~ >
```

because linux *is* adding the newline.

Comment: Thank :) .That worked for me . I was trying sed command to replace new line but that didn't worked for me . Not sure why not . but this did . Thanks